# Docker build error: "Cannot read file '/app/src/@iconify/tsconfig.json'" during yarn install

Tags: docker, nuxt.js, yarnpkg

I'm trying to build a Docker image for my application using the provided Dockerfile and package.json files. However, I'm encountering an error during the yarn install step in the Docker build process. The error message I'm receiving is:

```
error TS5083: Cannot read file '/app/src/@iconify/tsconfig.json'.
```

Here's my Dockerfile:

```
# Use an official Node.js base image with the latest LTS version
FROM node:lts-alpine as builder

# Set the working directory inside the container
WORKDIR /app

# Copy package.json and yarn.lock to the container
COPY package*.json yarn.lock ./

# Install project dependencies using Yarn
RUN yarn install

# Copy the rest of the application code to the container
COPY . .

# Build the Vue.js application
RUN yarn dev

# Stage 2: Use a lightweight nginx image to serve the static files
FROM nginx:latest

# Copy the built Vue.js application from the previous stage
COPY --from=builder /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html

# Copy nginx configuration file
COPY docker/nginx/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

# Expose port 80 for the Vue.js application to run
EXPOSE 80

# Start nginx server
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

The error seems to be related to the build:icons script defined in the package.json file, which executes the following commands:

```
tsc -b src/@iconify
node src/@iconify/build-icons.js
```

ERROR
[ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lUico.png)
It appears that the TypeScript compiler (tsc) is unable to find the tsconfig.json file located at /app/src/@iconify/tsconfig.json, resulting in the error.

I'm unsure why this error is occurring during the Docker build process, as the yarn install command should only be installing project dependencies and not executing the build:icons script.

Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

What could be causing this error during the yarn install command in my Docker build process, and how can I resolve it?